# Could not broadcast input array from shape (2,2,3) into shape (224,224,3) - extracting blocks from NumPy Array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, patch

I'm trying to create several patches with a specified size - 1800, 224, 224, 3 - from a raster image (1, 4646, 4827, 3) through the following code:

```
import numpy as np

image = images_final
tiles = np.zeros((1400, 224, 224, 3))

c = 0

for i in range(0, image.shape[1], 2):  

for j in range(0, image.shape[2], 2):

    tiles[c] = image[:, i:i+2, j:j+2]
    c += 1
```

However, I keep getting the following message: ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (2,2,3) into shape (224,224,3).

I also tried the following code:

```
def for_loop_split(image: np.ndarray, kernel_size: tuple):
img_height, img_width, channels = image.shape
tile_height, tile_width = kernel_size

tiled_array = np.zeros ((img_height // tile_height,
                       img_width // tile_width,
                       tile_height,
                       tile_width,
                       channels))
  y = x = 0
  for i in range(0, img_height, tile_height):
  for j in range (0,img_width,tile_width):
  tiled_array[y][x] = image[i:i+tile_height,
                            j:j+tile_width,
                            :channels]
  x += 1
  y += 1
  x = 0 
  return tiled_array

 patches = stride_split(img,tilesize)
```

BUT the output is (20, 21, 224, 224, 3), and I need it to be *number of patches* x 224 x 224 x 3, the last corresponding to the channels of the raster.

I know that there are several solutions for the same error, but they are not applicable for my specific issue. Could anyone help me with that?

Comment: `patches = patches.reshape(-1, *patches.shape[2:])`

Comment: Correct the indents and function name use.  The function (not yours?) clearly makes a 5d array.  Read the `np.zeros` call, and `x,y` double loop.